# How to pass a parameter in getStaticProps in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I just want to ask how can I call an API when a user "click the search button" and display the appropriate result in NextJS. Thank you!

This is the API I'm using https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Steak and note the "Steak" word is the food I want to see.

Here is my url in development mode http://localhost:3000/search/steak/.

I want to pass the "steak" in getStaticProps and pass the result of getStaticProps in my component.

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Steak'
  );

  return {
    props: {
      meals: res.data,
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it. `GetStaticProps` render the page at build time, so you can't render a page based on user request.
I suggest you to read [this docs, section 'when I should use GetStaticProps'](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getstaticprops).
You can use react state, or `GetServerSideProps` (read the same docs).
You can also static render a bunch of page using `GetStaticPath` and pass, for example, the 10 most searched foods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths) if you are using dynamic routes.

You can use `search/[slug].js` as a dynamic route in your file based routing.

Then, in `[slug].js` you would have something like:

```
export default function Page({ response }) {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(response)})</div>
}

// get all the possible paths for the individual ingredients
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const data = await axios.get(
    'www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?i=list'
  );

  return {
    paths: data.meals.map((ingredient) => ({
      params: { slug: ingredient.strIngredient.toString().toLowerCase. },
    })),
    fallback: false, // can also be true or 'blocking'
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params
  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${slug}`
  );

  return {
    props: {
      response
    },
  }
}
```